How to make a Drag and Drop with LazyColumn in Jetpack compose?
I'm making a feature called DragAndDrop with LazyColumn. 
To implement this feature, I referred to an article by Suraj Sau. 
The article is great but it's slightly different from what i want to make.
The article introduces a way to implement DragAndDrop by dragging the entire item area, but i want to make it by dragging a specific area within the item. 
I'll show you.

You can see the hamburger button. That's the point that i want to drag. 
So i set the Modifier.pointerInput(Unit) at the hamburger button like below. 
fun DragDropList(
    items: List<ReorderItem>,
    onMove: (Int, Int) -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    var overscrollJob by remember { mutableStateOf<Job?>(null) }
    val dragDropListState = rememberDragDropListState(onMove = onMove)

    LazyColumn(
        modifier = modifier,
        state = dragDropListState.lazyListState,
    ) {
        itemsIndexed(
            items = items,
            key = { _, item -> item.id }
        ) { index, item ->
            val isCurrentItem = index == dragDropListState.currentIndexOfDraggedItem
            val draggingModifier = if (isCurrentItem) {
                Modifier
                    .zIndex(1f)
                    .graphicsLayer {
                        translationY = dragDropListState.elementDisplacement ?: 0f
                    }
            } else {
                Modifier
                    .zIndex(0f)
                    .animateItemPlacement(
                        animationSpec = tween(
                            durationMillis = 300,
                        )
                    )
            }

            Row(
                modifier = draggingModifier
                    .background(Color.White, shape = RoundedCornerShape(4.dp))
                    .fillMaxWidth(),
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
            ) {
                Image(
                    modifier = Modifier.pointerInput(Unit) {
                        detectDragGesturesImmediately(
                            onDragStart = { offset ->
                                dragDropListState.onDragStart(offset)
                            },
                            onDrag = { change, offset ->
                                change.consume()
                                dragDropListState.onDrag(offset)

                                if (overscrollJob?.isActive == true)
                                    return@detectDragGesturesImmediately

                                dragDropListState.checkForOverScroll()
                                    .takeIf { it != 0f }
                                    ?.let {
                                        overscrollJob =
                                            scope.launch { dragDropListState.lazyListState.scrollBy(it) }
                                    }
                                    ?: run { overscrollJob?.cancel() }
                            },
                            onDragEnd = { dragDropListState.onDragInterrupted() },
                            onDragCancel = { dragDropListState.onDragInterrupted() }
                        )
                    },
                    imageVector = ImageVector.vectorResource(id = R.drawable.ic_hamburger),
                    contentDescription = "hamburger button",
                )
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.size(16.dp))
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier.height(80.dp),
                    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
                ) {
                    Text(
                        text = "Item ${item.id}",
                        textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                    )
                }

            }
            HorizontalDivider(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .height(1.dp),
                color = Color.Black,
            )
        }
    }
}

But it's so weird because i can only drag the first item even though i dragged 2 or 3 items in the LazyColumn. 
 
What's going on here? How can i make the DragAndDrop by dragging specific area within the item of LazyColumn?
[Edit]
This code is still weird but I changed some code.I can handle the hamburger button but when i move the first item to somewhere, it will be broken. please check the code and i hope we can solve this together.
Full code 
MainActivity.kt
@ExperimentalFoundationApi
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            DraggableLazyListTheme {
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    val items = remember {
                        mutableStateListOf(ReorderItem(id = 1, title = "1 item"),
                            ReorderItem(id = 2, title = "2 item"),
                            ReorderItem(id = 3, title = "3 item"),
                            ReorderItem(id = 4, title = "4 item"),
                            ReorderItem(id = 5, title = "5 item"),
                            ReorderItem(id = 6, title = "6 item"),
                            ReorderItem(id = 7, title = "7 item"),
                            ReorderItem(id = 8, title = "8 item"),
                            ReorderItem(id = 9, title = "9 item"),
                            ReorderItem(id = 10, title = "10 item"),
                            ReorderItem(id = 11, title = "11 item"),
                            ReorderItem(id = 12, title = "12 item"),
                            ReorderItem(id = 13, title = "13 item"),
                            ReorderItem(id = 14, title = "14 item"),
                            ReorderItem(id = 15, title = "15 item"),
                            ReorderItem(id = 16, title = "16 item"),
                            ReorderItem(id = 17, title = "17 item"),
                            ReorderItem(id = 18, title = "18 item"),)
                    }

                    DragDropList(items = items.toList(), onMove = { fromPosition, toPosition ->
                        items.move(fromPosition, toPosition)
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

DragDropList.kt [Edited]
@ExperimentalFoundationApi
@Composable
fun DragDropList(
    items: List<ReorderItem>,
    onMove: (Int, Int) -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {

    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    var overscrollJob by remember { mutableStateOf<Job?>(null) }
    val dragDropListState = rememberDragDropListState(onMove = onMove)

    LazyColumn(
        modifier = modifier,
        state = dragDropListState.lazyListState,
    ) {
        itemsIndexed(
            items = items,
            key = { _, item -> item.id }
        ) { index, item ->
            val isCurrentItem = index == dragDropListState.currentIndexOfDraggedItem
            val draggingModifier = if (isCurrentItem) {
                Modifier
                    .zIndex(1f)
                    .graphicsLayer {
                        translationY = dragDropListState.elementDisplacement ?: 0f
                    }
            } else {
                Modifier
                    .zIndex(0f)
                    .animateItemPlacement(
                        animationSpec = tween(
                            durationMillis = 300,
                        )
                    )
            }

            Row(
                modifier = draggingModifier
                    .background(Color.White, shape = RoundedCornerShape(4.dp))
                    .fillMaxWidth(),
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
            ) {
                Image(
                    imageVector = ImageVector.vectorResource(id = R.drawable.ic_hamburger),
                    contentDescription = "hamburger button",
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .pointerInput(item.id) {
                            detectDragGesturesImmediately(
                                onDragStart = { offset ->
                                    dragDropListState.onDragStart(offset, item.id)
                                },
                                onDrag = { change, offset ->
                                    change.consume()
                                    dragDropListState.onDrag(offset)

                                    if (overscrollJob?.isActive == true)
                                        return@detectDragGesturesImmediately

                                    dragDropListState.checkForOverScroll()
                                        .takeIf { it != 0f }
                                        ?.let {
                                            Log.d("TEST", "scroll float = $it")
                                            overscrollJob = scope.launch {
                                                dragDropListState.lazyListState.scrollBy(it)
                                            }
                                        }
                                        ?: run { overscrollJob?.cancel() }
                                },
                                onDragEnd = { dragDropListState.onDragInterrupted() },
                                onDragCancel = { dragDropListState.onDragInterrupted() }
                            )
                        }
                )
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(16.dp))
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier.height(80.dp),
                    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
                ) {
                    Text(
                        text = "Item ${item.id}",
                        textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                    )
                }
            }
            HorizontalDivider(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .height(1.dp),
                color = Color.Black,
            )
        }
    }
}

DragGestureDectectorEx.kt
suspend fun PointerInputScope.detectDragGesturesImmediately(
    onDragStart: (Offset) -> Unit = { },
    onDragEnd: () -> Unit = { },
    onDragCancel: () -> Unit = { },
    onDrag: (change: PointerInputChange, dragAmount: Offset) -> Unit
) {
    awaitEachGesture {
        try {
            val down = awaitFirstDown(requireUnconsumed = false)
            onDragStart.invoke(down.position)

            if (
                drag(down.id) {
                    onDrag(it, it.positionChange())
                    it.consume()
                }
            ) {
                // consume up if we quit drag gracefully with the up
                currentEvent.changes.fastForEach {
                    if (it.changedToUp()) it.consume()
                }
                onDragEnd()
            } else {
                onDragCancel()
            }
        } catch (c: CancellationException) {
            onDragCancel()
            throw c
        }
    }
}


**DragDropListState.kt**
@Composable
fun rememberReorderableListState(
    lazyListState: LazyListState = rememberLazyListState(),
    onMove: (Int, Int) -> Unit,
): ReorderableListState {
    return remember { ReorderableListState(lazyListState = lazyListState, onMove = onMove) }
}

class ReorderableListState(
    val lazyListState: LazyListState,
    private val onMove: (Int, Int) -> Unit
) {
    var draggedDistance by mutableStateOf(0f)

    // used to obtain initial offsets on drag start
    var initiallyDraggedElement by mutableStateOf<LazyListItemInfo?>(null)

    var currentIndexOfDraggedItem by mutableStateOf<Int?>(null)

    val initialOffsets: Pair<Int, Int>?
        get() = initiallyDraggedElement?.let { Pair(it.offset, it.offsetEnd) }

    val elementDisplacement: Float?
        get() = currentIndexOfDraggedItem
            ?.let { lazyListState.getVisibleItemInfoFor(absoluteIndex = it) }
            ?.let { item -> (initiallyDraggedElement?.offset ?: 0f).toFloat() + draggedDistance - item.offset }

    val currentElement: LazyListItemInfo?
        get() = currentIndexOfDraggedItem?.let {
            lazyListState.getVisibleItemInfoFor(absoluteIndex = it)
        }

    var overscrollJob by mutableStateOf<Job?>(null)

    fun onDragStart(offset: Offset) {
        lazyListState.layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo
            .firstOrNull { item -> offset.y.toInt() in item.offset..(item.offset + item.size) }
            ?.also {
                currentIndexOfDraggedItem = it.index
                initiallyDraggedElement = it
            }
    }

    fun onDragInterrupted() {
        draggedDistance = 0f
        currentIndexOfDraggedItem = null
        initiallyDraggedElement = null
        overscrollJob?.cancel()
    }

    fun onDrag(offset: Offset) {
        draggedDistance += offset.y

        initialOffsets?.let { (topOffset, bottomOffset) ->
            val startOffset = topOffset + draggedDistance
            val endOffset = bottomOffset + draggedDistance

            currentElement?.let { hovered ->
                lazyListState.layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo
                    .filterNot { item -> item.offsetEnd < startOffset || item.offset > endOffset || hovered.index == item.index }
                    .firstOrNull { item ->
                        val delta = startOffset - hovered.offset
                        when {
                            delta > 0 -> (endOffset > item.offsetEnd)
                            else -> (startOffset < item.offset)
                        }
                    }
                    ?.also { item ->
                        currentIndexOfDraggedItem?.let { current -> onMove.invoke(current, item.index) }
                        currentIndexOfDraggedItem = item.index
                    }
            }
        }
    }

    fun checkForOverScroll(): Float {
        return initiallyDraggedElement?.let {
            val startOffset = it.offset + draggedDistance
            val endOffset = it.offsetEnd + draggedDistance

            return@let when {
                draggedDistance > 0 -> (endOffset - lazyListState.layoutInfo.viewportEndOffset).takeIf { diff -> diff > 0 }
                draggedDistance < 0 -> (startOffset - lazyListState.layoutInfo.viewportStartOffset).takeIf { diff -> diff < 0 }
                else -> null
            }
        } ?: 0f
    }
}

RedorderableList_Extensions.kt
/*
    LazyListItemInfo.index is the item's absolute index in the list
    Based on the item's "relative position" with the "currently top" visible item,
    this returns LazyListItemInfo corresponding to it
*/
fun LazyListState.getVisibleItemInfoFor(absoluteIndex: Int): LazyListItemInfo? {
    return this.layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo.getOrNull(absoluteIndex - this.layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo.first().index)
}

/*
  Bottom offset of the element in Vertical list
*/
val LazyListItemInfo.offsetEnd: Int
    get() = this.offset + this.size

/*
   Moving element in the list
*/
fun <T> MutableList<T>.move(from: Int, to: Int) {
    Collections.swap(this, from, to)
}


was you able to fix this?

@MohammedFareed not yet. DId you make it?

Did you fix it ?

@AhmedElsayed Not yet..But i almost made it.The only problem is that when I move an item to the top, the entire list changes.

I edited the code please check it.
